# vb.net incremental node value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Hello I have this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
-<DATA> 
  -<patient_no.1> 
      <Patient_name/>Sylvester</Patient_name> 
      <card_number/>1234567890</card_number> 
   </patient_no.1> 
 </DATA>
```

I want to programaticaly update the xml next time whenever the data is updated with new data so that the new dile is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
    -<DATA>
      -<patient_no.1> 
          <Patient_name/>Sylvester</Patient_name> 
          <card_number/>1234567890</card_number> 
       </patient_no.1> 
      -<patient_no.2> 
          <Patient_name/>Arnold</Patient_name> 
          <card_number/>1234567</card_number> 
       </patient_no.2> 
     </DATA>
```

Note that the `<patient_no.>` has increased to 2. This is what i want to automate. The `patient_name` and `Card_number` are updated through textboxes.
I know i'll have to use xmlread/xmlwrite but i am unable to figure out. I have reached to this far:

```
        Dim Dc As XmlDocument
        Dim root As XmlNode
        Dim node As XmlNode

        Dc = New XmlDocument()
        Dc.Load(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\patient.xml")
        root = Dc.SelectSingleNode("/DATA")
        If Dc.SelectSingleNode("/DATA/NodeToBeUpdated") _
            Is Nothing Then
            node = root.InsertBefore(
                Dc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "NodeToBeUpdated", ""),
            Dc.SelectSingleNode("/DATA/NodeToBeUpdated"))
            node.AppendChild(
                Dc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Patient_name", ""))
            node.AppendChild(
                Dc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "card_number", ""))

        End If
        Dc.Save(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory & "\patient.xml")
```

Apart from this i would also like to know how to display details of each `patient_no.` into seperate table or datagridview

Comment: Is there some reason for your specific XML format vs. something more typical, such as `<patient no="1">`?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Yes because I want my program to show the information of the particular patient in the table. So insted of `patient_no.`
It can be the date and time of the entry in textbox so at the time of retrival, patient addmition as well as discharge date can be seen. I want to save the date and time programatically so that the info filler doesnt play foul. The above xml format is saved by my xmlwrite code. Moreover if someone suggests better way than mine, please do it, i'll be more than happy to adapt it.